# Powershell Code returns systemerror or dont run

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to run some PowerShell Commands in my C# Project via `System.Management.Automation;` but if I try the following Code I will get an Systemerror:

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$AppList = 'Microsoft.3DBuilder', 'Microsoft.BingSports'" +
                                         "ForEach ($App in $AppList) " +
                                         "{ " +
                                         "$PackageFullName = (Get-AppxPackage $App).PackageFullName" +
                                         "$ProPackageFullName = (Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -online | where {$_.Displayname -eq $App}).PackageName" +
                                         "write-host $PackageFullName" +
                                         "Write-Host $ProPackageFullName" +
                                         "if ($PackageFullName) " +
                                         "{ " +
                                         "Write-Host 'Removing Package: $App' " +
                                         "} " +
                                         "else " +
                                         "{ " +
                                         "Write-Host 'Unable to find package: $App' " +
                                         "} " +
                                         "if ($ProPackageFullName) " +
                                         "{ " +
                                         "Write-Host 'Removing Provisioned Package: $ProPackageFullName' " +
                                         "} " +
                                         "else " +
                                         "{ Write-Host 'Unable to find provisioned package: $App' " +
                                         "} " +
                                         "} ");

            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
            string output = "";
            foreach (PSObject outputItem in PSOutput)
            {
                if (outputItem != null)
                {
                    output += outputItem.BaseObject.ToString();
                    output += "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "Output ist null";
                }
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            {
                return output;
            }
            else
                return "Output ist empty";
        }
```

If I add `;` behind each argument then nothing will happen. I tried this code many times in PowerShell and it's working there.
Is there a limit how long a Script can be or something like that?

Comment: After concatenating these strings your code looks like this `$AppList = 'Microsoft.3DBuilder', 'Microsoft.BingSports'ForEach ($App in $AppList) `. *"If I add `;` behind each argument then nothing will happen."*. Then add those `;` and update your question. Let's see how it looks after this.

Comment: Please *show* the error. Why do we always need to ask for that?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I wrote the error. it's "Systemerror" nothing else.